# How can I cancel a DataGrid ToolTip before its shown?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I've got a DataGrid that shows a tooltip on each item.. but there are a few items where there shouldn't be a tooltip. So I thought I could prevent the being showed.

```
protected function toolTipStart(event:ToolTipEvent) : void
{
  LOG.debug('Start  ' + event); 

  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

But it does not work. Has anyone an idea?

regards
Cyrill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stopImmedatePropogation will just stop further event listeners from catching the event; it does not have a relation to whether or not the toolTip is created.

I'm pretty sure you set the toolTip property of the [event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:toolTipStart) to null; then the toolTip will not show up.

Comment: I tried to set event to null in the event listeners (TOOLTIP_START, TOOLTIP_CREATE, TOOLTIP_SHOW) .. but had no impact on the tooltip.

But I could set the tooltip invisible

event.tooltip.visible = false;

thanks for your help